# Nginx port redirection on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and i would like to make a port forward from a given server to another. The idea is I connect to the server xxx.xx.xx.xx on the port say 46 and then it redirects me to a server yyy.yyy.yyy.yy on the port 20003. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please see http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask.  Post your current configurations, state your goals and specific error your are receiving.  What results do you get now?   Unlike some sites, SF is geared to professional conversations about system administration not a how-to or tutorial discussion group.

Answer (score 2):

```
    server {
      listen xxx.xx.xx.xx:46;
      location / {
        proxy_pass                              http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yy:20003;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host                   $host;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding        "";
        proxy_next_upstream                     off;
        proxy_read_timeout                      7200;
        proxy_connect_timeout                   7200;
        add_header X-Node-Status                $upstream_status;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `nginx` then, unless you strictly need HTTP protocol proxying, use `rinetd` or something else that simply forwards the TCP connection and is protocol-agnostic. It *is* limited to TCP, admittedly, but since you appear to be using HTTP that shouldn't be a limiting factor.

`rinetd` is dubbed the "Internet redirection server" and can be found in various distros using your package management tools and even exists for Windows. Its home page and documentation can be found [here](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/).

Alternatively you can use DNAT/SNAT if you have a firewall like `iptables`/netfilter, but `rinetd` is the simpler method.

The configuration is as simple as putting (format `bindaddress bindport connectaddress connectport`):

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx 46 yyy.yyy.yyy.yy 20003
```

into your configuration. For more options and details read the friendly manual.

---

While I really like `nginx` and use it in all kinds of scenarios, artificially constraining your question to `nginx` is typical of questions that ask "how can I accomplish X using Y" instead of "I want to accomplish Z". Ask by stating your goal, not by describing a predefined path and predefined tools, unless there are special reasons (which you then should state clearly).